# Style reset password page? /wp-login.php?action=rp

Tags: customization, wp-enqueue-style

I cannot figure out how to style the reset password page. And I do not mean the page where you request it, I mean the page you are shown when you click the link in the email to set your new password.
The URL is `/wp-login.php?action=rp`

And looks like this

[image]

And the confirmation page:

[image]

How do I load my custom styles for these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [login_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_enqueue_scripts), you can load styles or scripts with it.

Example:

```
function login_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'loginCSS', '/my-styles.css', false ); 
}

add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'login_styles', 10 );
```